# Why Observer's Saved method not working for while update the record in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have project in laravel 5.3 and i am using Observer for activity log of user, for that i have created one obeserver with saved() and deleted() method.

The saved() method is working fine for new record, while update the record saved() is not getting call nor updated() method.

I also try with deleted() method, that is also not getting call, here below is my code, please help.

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        // echo "dsd"; die();
    }

    public function saved($user)
    {
        if ($user->wasRecentlyCreated == true) {
            // Data was just created
            $action = 'created';
        } else {
            // Data was updated
            $action = 'updated';
        }
        
        UserAction::create([
            'user_id'      => Auth::user()->id,
            'action'       => $action,
            'action_model' => $user->getTable(),
            'action_id'    => $user->id
        ]);
    }

    public function deleting($user)
    {
        dd($user); 
    }
}



public static function boot() { 
        parent::boot(); 
        parent::observe(new \App\Observers\UserObserver); 
    }
```

Comment: Can you show how you update or delete your model to test if it works?

Comment: I am using update query like this, 

\App\Discounts::where('id',$request->edit_id)->update($data);

Comment: Updated my answer with why your events is not triggering

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems ok, so i guess something bigger is at fault here. Normally the best practice for registering observers is to do it in a provider class `boot()` method.

```
public function boot()
{
    User::observe(UserObserver::class);
}
```

**EDIT**

For model events to trigger you have to use the model and not update the data through a query.

```
$discount = Discounts::find($request->edit_id);
$discount->fill($data);
$discount->save();
```

Comment: i'm not certain this is the concrete fault, your code seems fine, but check if it works.

Comment: I already put boot method in Model. and it is working for add,but update and delete is not working. That is the problem.

Comment: as i wrote do it in a provider class